# R - Delete columns which names are not included in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have 2 dataframes like this(Code is below):

```
>MainFrame
   Station        V1        V2       V3
1  Station1  5.000000  4.000000 10.00000
2  Station2  8.571429  5.714286 17.14286
3  Station3 12.142857  7.428571 24.28571
4  Station4 15.714286  9.142857 31.42857
5  Station6 19.285714 10.857143 38.57143
6  Station7 22.857143 12.571429 45.71429
7  Station9 26.428571 14.285714 52.85714
8  Station10 30.000000 16.000000 60.00000

>SubFrame
    Date     Station1 Station3 Station5 Station7 Station8
1 20000608        5      4.0       10        5        5
2 20000609       10      6.4       20       10       10
3 20000610       15      8.8       30       15       15
4 20000611       20     11.2       40       20       20
5 20000612       25     13.6       50       25       25
6 20000613       30     16.0       60       30       30
```

I want to check now if the Station-Names (column-names) from the SubFrame are contained in the first column of the MainFrame. If not, I want to delete these columns in the Subframe. I only want to have Stations in the SubFrame that are also listed in the MainFrame.

In this case I want to delete the columns of Station5 and Station8 in the SubFrame because they are not included in the MainFrame.

The result should be like this:

```
      Date    Station1 Station3 Station7
1 20000608        5      4.0        5
2 20000609       10      6.4       10
3 20000610       15      8.8       15
4 20000611       20     11.2       20
5 20000612       25     13.6       25
6 20000613       30     16.0       30
```

Any idea how to do that?

Here is the code of my 2 testframes:

```
x1= c("Station1", "Station2", "Station3", "Station4", "Station6", "Station7", "Station9", "Station10")
x2= seq(5, 30, length=8)
x3= seq(4, 16, length=8)
x4= seq(10, 60, length=8) 

MainFrame = data.frame(Station=x1, V1=x2, V2=x3, V3=x4) 

x1= c("20000608", "20000609", "20000610", "20000611", "20000612", "20000613") 
x2= seq(5, 30, length=6)
x3= seq(4, 16, length=6)
x4= seq(10, 60,length=6) 
x5= seq(5, 30, length=6)
x6= seq(5, 30, length=6)

SubFrame = data.frame(Date=x1, Station1=x2, Station3=x3, Station5=x4, Station7=x5, Station8 =x6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset your `SubFrame` dataframe by specifying that you only want the columns that are in the `MainFrame` by doing the following:

`unique(MainFrame$Station)` yields:

```
unique(MainFrame$Station)
[1] "Station1"  "Station2"  "Station3"  "Station4"  "Station6"  "Station7"  "Station9"  "Station10"
```

*Note you must have this column as a character col. You can do this by setting:

```
MainFrame$Station <- as.character(MainFrame$Station)
```

Then you can subset:

```
SubFrame[,colnames(SubFrame) %in% unique(MainFrame$Station)]
  Station1 Station3 Station7
1        5      4.0        5
2       10      6.4       10
3       15      8.8       15
4       20     11.2       20
5       25     13.6       25
6       30     16.0       30
```

We're missing the Date column, so we can pull that in by taking the above and using `cbind` with just the Date column:

```
cbind(Date = SubFrame$Date, SubFrame[,colnames(SubFrame) %in% unique(MainFrame$Station)])

      Date Station1 Station3 Station7
1 20000608        5      4.0        5
2 20000609       10      6.4       10
3 20000610       15      8.8       15
4 20000611       20     11.2       20
5 20000612       25     13.6       25
6 20000613       30     16.0       30
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats working very well! I would have never been able to think of that!